# Raspberry pi aneometer

Tags: raspbian

I bought [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/261912230946?_trksid=p2060353.m1438.l2648&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) aneometer online. It sends voltage pulse when it makes one full revolution. How can I hook it up to Raspberry Pi? I guess that I need to convert analog signal to digital, right?

(Sorry for stupid question I'm new to Raspberry Pi)

Comment: Do you have a datasheet or other documentation about the device?

Comment: No, it's cheap chinese aneometer.

Comment: This is going to be difficult for anyone to answer if there are no specifications other than the listing. Is that a phone cable connector at the end? I suggest you take it apart if possible and see what wires lead to what. It will probably give you more information than we can give you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anemometer probably just contains a reed switch which is closed by a magnet once per revolution.

Connect one end of the switch to a Pi ground through a 1k resistor.  Connect the other end of the switch to a Pi gpio.  Set the internal pull-up on the Pi gpio to 3.3V.

The anemometer will then normally read high (1).  It will read low (0) once per revolution.  It's then just a question of counting the pulses (high to low transitions).

Comment: Hi, I don't understand this part "Set the internal pull-up on the Pi gpio to 3.3V.", then I need 3 wires? Let's say I connect my wires to pin 20(ground) and 22(gpio25), where goes the 3rd one? 
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The internal pull-up is handled within the SOC (System on a Chip).  The library you use will have a function to enable or disable the internal pull-up/down resistors.  The pull-up is quite weak.  It is enough to fix the input high but will easily be overridden by the switch going low.